# Ember TodoMVC app with Rails backend No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, cors, ember-cli, todomvc

I'm trying to follow the Ember Getting Started guide and build a TodoMVC app but use Ember-CLI with Rails as a backend. Unfortunately I'm running into an issue with cross site domain stuff. I'm getting this error message with I try and do a post request:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/todos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

On the Rails side I have Rack Cors installed. I have it added to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

And in my `application.rb` file I have:

```
module Todoemberrails
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.enabled = false

    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my controller:

```
class Api::TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Todo.all
  end

  def show
    render json: Todo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

    if todo.save
      render json: todo, status: :created
    else
      render json: todo.errors, status: :unprocessed
    end
  end

  private

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :is_completed)
  end
end
```

And inside of my Ember app in `app/adapters/application.js` I have:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
});
```

Comment: Why is localhost:4200 sending the request?  Are you running the app from there?  If so, would changing your host to host: 'localhost:4200/api' help?

Comment: I'm using Ember-CLI so it is using its own webserver to host the ember app, so no I couldn't change the rails server to localhost:4200 because they can't be running on the same port.

Comment: I cannot provide a solution, but if you are stuck I recommend having a look at the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter`. Combined with gem `active_model_serializers` it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't allow this by default, to prevent Cross Site Scripting.

If you want to allow this accross the board, you can add this to your ApplicationController:

```
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']      = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods']     = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age']           = '1728000'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  end
```

Sounds ok for a getting started with Ember guide, **but not for a production app.**